# Where do I start giving a shape neon glows and lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I know that stackexchange isn't a place with tutorials and I don't need a guide, I just need a point to start :)

I have followed this tutorial here:
thearthunters.com/tutorial-create-3d-logo-with-polygonal-lasso-tool/

And created a logo like this:

[image]

Now what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

The problem is here that I have no idea where to start, which tools were used to create this. I did some cool graphics, lines, shapes, experiments with gradients/shades.

If there's someone who can point me the way, how the author achieved that result, I would be grateful :)

Comment: Looks like a combination of applying some outerglow and hand painting the glows with a soft brush, then changing the opacity and blending modes

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version, I think it's more easy than the full pro approach with a frightening mountain of layers, masks, modes, etc...

[image]

1. The greyscale shape. NOTE: Nearly mid grey only, no white, no black
2. The shape colorized Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation, Colorize. Avoid extreme brightness, darkness and saturation to have room for effects. The layer count LC is now 1.
3. Draw white lines. Merge them to one layer. LC=2
4. Add a layer. Paint solid white. LC=3.
5. Blur the solid white to have gradients. Make a selection with the base shape. Use it to delete the spillovers. LC=3

6.Merge whites to one layer (not necessary, keeping them separate leaves more control). Goto Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation to give a light blue color to the whites. Avoid extreme saturation. LC=2

7. Add a new layer with blending mode Color. Spray purple and red with a low opacity smooth brush. Delete the spillovers. LC=3
8. Add a new layer for highlights. Tahe a smooth low opacity brush and spray white. Delete the spillovers.LC=4
9. Add a dark (not black) test background. Duplicate other layers, merge the duplicates and duplicate the result. Beware to lose your work layers. Blur one of the merges. It's your outer glow. If it's too faint, duplicate it.Put it just above the background. Adjust the other merge to black, blur it a little. It's your drop shadow. Move the outer glow and the drop shadow a little to have greater effect. LC=7
10. Erased the exessive highlight off at the upper left corner. Adjusted the Whites layer a little darker and more blue in the Hue/Saturation dialog. Adjusted the base shape to have more contrast and higher saturation.

Development ideas: Get non-destruktive. The layer stack grows, but you keep full control.There's another answer that quides to that way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm glowing effect are pretty tricky, you can add a line with your **bright** color on it, blur it, and change the blending mode.
The blending mode could help you a lot with the color problem.

By the way, i see a little bit glow from the effect, for that you can double the "glow effect" layer, duplicate it to make a copy of it, and then blur it a bit to create the "glow" effect of yours. :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this is all achieved via gradients or soft brushes and blending modes.

[image]

This is a flat blue rectangle on a dark background. The only other color added was a few red gradients. All the color variations in the blue were pulled off via blend modes and white or black gradients. Black gradients were set to `Color Burn` and opacity adjusted. White gradients were set to `Overlay`, `Color Dodge`, or `Linear Dodge` and opacity adjusted.

Here it is without the red.... Just a blue rectangle with black or white gradients on top of it.

[image]

And Here is the Layer structure....

Many layers could have been combined/merged but I left them as individual layers to better show the overall construction.

[image]